# Regex Issue - Cannot get the correct value after title="

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am having issues with regex and I don't know how to proceed. I need to get the value "ITOM Control Board Major Alarm 4 Set" and I am not able to do so since I have two different set of line code.

Regex Website: http://regexstorm.net/tester [My current tester results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LURHK.png)

Pattern: `(?<=title=")(.*)`

Values:

```
<td class="vt" title="" ng-non-bindable="" data-original-title="ITOM Control Board Major Alarm 4 Set 
Message: User

<td class="vt" title="ITOM Control Board Major Alarm 4 Set 
Message: User
```

[Here is the image for what is happening at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Uih.png)

Comment: Since the same text appears on the 1st and 4th lines, I have to ask: which line would you want to extract the text from, and what exactly is your logic for deciding? You want it from the `data-original-title` attribute or specifically the `title` attribute when it's not empty, or what?

Comment: I could imagine a solution like `(?<=title=")([^"]*)` if you know the text you want to extract never contains double quotes, or maybe `(?<=title=")([^"].*)` to say take the text only if it doesn't immediately start with a closing quote, but you'll need to give us more details before we can really help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the text to search is exactly as stated then this might help:

```
title="([^\n"]+)
```

This will match anything after `title="` that is not a quote (`"`) or a new line (`\n`)

See the example: https://regex101.com/r/GVEKjF/1

If the text to search has the title surrounded by both quotes, then try:

```
title="([^"]+)
```

Hope this helps